# Remove data from a file stream

Tags: java, file

I've the following scenario: I want to load the content of a file, remove some information (f.e. a specific byte sequence) and store the modified content back to the file.
Is there a kind of read-write-stream for that purpose or can I only realize it by using a InputStream/OutputStream pairing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik there is no such thing as "one" stream that can be used to read *and* write. You have to use two streams. Java 8 API helps us a little here.

See the following snippet as example (which shows one of many ways to achieve read / manipulate / write file content).

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;

      public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            final Path filePath = Paths.get("D:/test.txt");
            final String sequenceToRemove = "foobar";

            /*
             * Read content from file
             */
            final String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(filePath));

            /*
             * Remove content partially
             */
            final String modifiedContent = content.replace(sequenceToRemove, "");

            /*
             * Write modified content to file
             */
            try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(filePath)) {
                writer.write(modifiedContent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!  You can check the docs for the `java.io` package [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) for yourself, but I don't think there's any kind of read/write stream to be had.